# OCaml not accepting type constructor for binary tree

Tags: ocaml, algebraic-data-types

I am trying to construct something like this

```
type ('a, 'b) btree = Empty | Node of ('a, 'b) * ('a, 'b) btree * ('a, 'b) btree
```

but it says syntax error around where the first asterisk is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a pair looks like `'a * 'b` so you want this:

```
type ('a, 'b) btree = 
  Empty |
  Node of 'a * 'b * ('a, 'b) btree * ('a, 'b) btree
```

Or possibly this:

```
type ('a, 'b) btree = 
  Empty |
  Node of ('a * 'b) * ('a, 'b) btree * ('a, 'b) btree
```

Comment: sweet it works! i got confused there with having to use a comma for the btree constructor and an asterix for the literal tuple element. thanks